# не запускается grub после установки ubuntu второй системой

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, установка

у меня есть следующая проблема. Есть ssd 128 гб, где установлен windows10 и hdd 1тб (диск d)
Решил установить ubuntu второй системой и сделал следующие действия. Выделил 20 гб с ssd для корневого каталога ubuntu и 50 гб на hdd для /home. Загрузочный раздел указал efi c файловой системой fat32. После перезагрузки не заходит в grub, а сразу загружается windows.